# Space navigation elements WordPress Twenty Ten Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

I am building a site on the WordPress Twenty Ten theme. I would like to style the navigation bar so the tabs are spread out across the top but am at a bit of a loss. 
Here is the navbar: http://screencast.com/t/AbIPglmGtQ
Here is the CSS: http://pastebin.com/pSnCGcrQ

Also, would anyone have a clue as to adding segmentation between the tabs ie" Home | About | Services?

Any help would be much appreciated. Would love to put a fork in this project before the holidays!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll probably want to create a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), because otherwise when TwentyTen is updated, you'll lose all of your customizations. As far as spacing them out - it depends... do you want them to be spaced without expanding the current width of each link, or do you want to expand each link's width also? Kind of confusing, but you can expand it by increasing the margin to something like:

```
margin: 0 15px;
```

But, that'll just spread them out more - the size of the links will stay the same. To change the size of the links, adjust the padding as well. I'd do a little combination of both.

For the separator, in header.php, appx line 85, you'll see something like:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

change that to:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'after'           => '|', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

That should add a | after each link on there. Hope that helps. Let us know!

Comment: Thank you Connor, it's a Christmas miracle. ;) The padding and margin adjustments worked perfectly, but sadly no love on the separations. Here's my code, perhaps I fouled it up? http://pastebin.com/qgj1KvTA Thanks again!

Comment: My apologies Alex - it should be 'link_after', instead of 'after'. If that doesn't help, email me: [firstname] @ [fullname] .com, and I'll be glad to help you out!

Comment: Hi Connor, it turns out this edit caused the child pages to disable in IE. The top level pages can be clicked on, put the child pages are disabled and disappear upon scrolling over them in IE. Beyond bizarre. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the site: http://www.econforensics.com

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/svx8hNeK

Thank you,

Alex